# Make a point of

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, can-modal

> '*You **can** borrow my car if you like*' is a more gracious offer
> than '*You **may** borrow it*'; the first presumes the granting of
> permission, while the second **makes a point of it**.

[CONTEXT](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=can) (I find the conclusive clause contradictory though)

> "The heightened formality of **may** sometimes highlights the
> speaker's role in giving permission.
> *You **may** leave the room when you are finished* implies that permission is given by the speaker.
> *You **can** leave the room when you are finished* implies that permission is part of a rule or policy rather than a decision on the
> speaker's part.
>
> For this reason, **may** sees considerable use in official
> announcements: *Students **may** pick up the application forms
> tomorrow*

What does *"make a point of it*" exactly mean here?

Comment: It simply **states neutrally** that permission is granted, without any other polite contations.

Comment: @fev its context goes on saying "_Students **can** take no more than three courses_ allows the possibility that a student who is unusually capable may take more, whereas _Students **may** take no more than three courses_ does not."

Comment: Yes, so? I don't understand your point.

Comment: English-speaking children are often corrected by their parents not to say, "Can I have a cookie?" but to say, "May I have a cookie?"  The first one is a demand (assuming permission and only asking whether a cookie exists) whereas the second one is a polite petition seeking permission.

Comment: @CanadianYankee _Generations of grammarians and schoolteachers have insisted that can should be used only to express the **capacity** to do something, and that may must be used to express **permission**_ http://odict.net/can/

Comment: The first example highlights that permission is being granted explicitly. That is what "makes a point of it" means -- to highlight something.

Answer (score 1):

The "it" in "makes a point of it" refers to the *granting of permission* earlier in the sentence. The contrast being made, therefore, is between the *presumption* that permission has been granted (i.e. "You **can** borrow..." assumes permission has been granted) versus the *emphasis* on permission being granted (i.e., "You **may** borrow..." means permission is now granted).

Comment: _Generations of grammarians and schoolteachers have insisted that can should be used only to express the **capacity** to do something, and that may must be used to express **permission**_ http://odict.net/can/

Comment: Please understand, @GJC, that I was interpreting the meaning of the sentence in OP's question, not advocating for its veracity.

Comment: I find the conclusive clause contradictory though: 
"The heightened formality of **may** sometimes highlights the speaker's role in giving permission.
_You **may** leave the room when you are finished_ implies that permission is given by the speaker.
_You **can** leave the room when you are finished_ implies that permission is part of a rule or policy rather than a decision on the speaker's part.

For this reason, **may** sees considerable use in official announcements: _Students **may** pick up the application forms tomorrow_ https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=can